# what happens in NebulaGraph database of error `can’t solve the start vids from the sentence`?

Tags: nebula-graph

why NebulaGraph must specify a starting vid? As in the manual https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/20.appendix/0.FAQ/

```
> GO FROM ${vids} ...
> MATCH (src) WHERE id(src) == ${vids}
# The "start vids" are explicitly given by ${vids}.
# CREATE TAG INDEX IF NOT EXISTS i_player ON player(name(20));
# REBUILD TAG INDEX i_player;

> LOOKUP ON player WHERE player.name == "abc" | ... YIELD ...
> MATCH (src) WHERE src.name == "abc" ...
# The "start vids" are found from the property index "name".
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because it requires start vids to begin a graph traversal. And full data scan is forbidden by design.